# How to subset a list with list comprehension using another list

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have a large list of dictionaries I want to subset, which looks like this:

```
first_list = [{'name':'James','gender':'M','address':'California'},{'name':'Tom','gender':'M','address':'California'},
{'name':'Jane','gender':'F','address':'Utah'},
{'name':'Kim','gender':'F','address':'Wisconsin'},
{'name':'Ron','gender':'M','address':'Montana'}]
```

I have another list, with names:

```
second_list = ['James', 'Tom']
```

I want to get the list where 'name' in the first list is not a part of the second list, which is simply removing James and Tom dictionaries.

```
[{'name':'Jane','gender':'F','address':'Utah'},
{'name':'Kim','gender':'F','address':'Wisconsin'},
{'name':'Ron','gender':'M','address':'Montana'}]
```

I tried using list comprehension, but I don't think this works with different lists:

```
third_list = [x for x in first_list if x['name'] != (y for y in second_list)]
```

This won't work, will return the same list as the first list. Is my syntax wrong?

Comment: `(y for y in second_list)` creates a generator object. Comparing that to anything else would be `False`. You might just want `if x['name'] not in second_list` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `not in` that will work for you.

```
third_list = [i for i in first_list if i['name'] not in second_list]
```

**Result**

```
[{'address': 'Utah', 'gender': 'F', 'name': 'Jane'},
 {'address': 'Wisconsin', 'gender': 'F', 'name': 'Kim'},
 {'address': 'Montana', 'gender': 'M', 'name': 'Ron'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work , because `(y for y in second_list)` is a generator, `x['name']` is a string , which means it will return `False` all the time, I suppose what you want is this:

```
>>> first_list = [{'name':'James','gender':'M','address':'California'},{'name':'Tom','gender':'M','address':'California'},
... {'name':'Jane','gender':'F','address':'Utah'},
... {'name':'Kim','gender':'F','address':'Wisconsin'},
... {'name':'Ron','gender':'M','address':'Montana'}]
>>>
>>>
>>> second_list = ['James', 'Tom']
>>>
>>> [x for x in first_list if x['name'] not in second_list]
[{'gender': 'F', 'name': 'Jane', 'address': 'Utah'}, {'gender': 'F', 'name': 'Kim', 'address': 'Wisconsin'}, {'gender': 'M', 'name': 'Ron', 'address': 'Montana'}]
```

Pythonic way to do this , try to use `filter` method:

```
>>> filter(lambda x:x["name"] not in second_list,first_list)
[{'gender': 'F', 'name': 'Jane', 'address': 'Utah'}, {'gender': 'F', 'name': 'Kim', 'address': 'Wisconsin'}, {'gender': 'M', 'name': 'Ron', 'address': 'Montana'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
third_list = [x for x in first_list if x['name'] not in second_list]
```